# Status 403 on calling WordPress on nginx without protocol prefix

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-403

When I call my webshop in Chrome or every other web browser without the https prefix I get a 403 status. I don't know why. The error appears since I installed and deleted the hummingbird plugin by wpmudev.

Here is my conf:

I use WordPress with woocommerce on an Ubuntu 14.04 aws ec2 instance. Additionally the site is protected with ssl. The NGINX Helper plugin is present and active but wasn't touched during this situation.

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

server {
   listen *:80;

   server_name example.com www.example.com 52.29.193.xxx;

        #root /home/wordpress/htdocs;
   root /var/www/letsencrypt;

   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      default_type "text/plain";
      root         /var/www/letsencrypt;
   }

        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

        #rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
   listen *:443 ssl;

   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;

   server_name example.com www.example.com 52.29.193.xxx;

   root /home/wordpress/htdocs;

   index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

   #rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com$1;

   port_in_redirect off;

   set $skip_cache 0;

        error_log off;
        access_log off;

   # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
   if ($request_method = POST) {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   
   if ($query_string != "") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   

   # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
   if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   

   if ($request_uri ~* "/home.*|/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*") {
           set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   if ($request_uri ~* "/en/home.*|/en/store.*|/en/cart.*|/en/my-account.*|/en/checkout.*|/en/addons.*") {
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }

   if ( $arg_add-to-cart != "" ) { 
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   if ( $cookie_woocommerce_items_in_cart != "0" ) {  
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
   if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }    

   # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
   location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
      access_log off; 
      log_not_found off; 
      expires max;
   }

   # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
   location ~ \.php$ {
      set $rt_session "";

      if ($http_cookie ~* "wc_session_cookie_[^=]*=([^%]+)%7C") {
                     set $rt_session wc_session_cookie_$1;
            }  
      if ($skip_cache = 0 ) {
         more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
         set $rt_session "";
      }
           fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$rt_session";

      try_files $uri =404;    
      include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/wordpress.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
           fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

      fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
      fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
   }
   location ~ /purge(/.*) {
       fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
   }  
   location /user {
         rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
   location = /xmlrpc.php {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
   }
   location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/wsoe/(.*?)\.csv$ {
      rewrite / permanent;
   }
}
```

If possible please deliver some explanation, so that I can learn something about this issue

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

server {
   listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
   listen *:443 ssl;

   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   root /home/wordpress/htdocs;

   index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

   port_in_redirect off;

   set $skip_cache 0;

        error_log off;
        access_log off;

   # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
   if ($request_method = POST) {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   
   if ($query_string != "") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   

   # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
   if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }   

   if ($request_uri ~* "/home.*|/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*") {
           set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   if ($request_uri ~* "/en/home.*|/en/store.*|/en/cart.*|/en/my-account.*|/en/checkout.*|/en/addons.*") {
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }

   if ( $arg_add-to-cart != "" ) { 
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   if ( $cookie_woocommerce_items_in_cart != "0" ) {  
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
   if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
   }

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }    

   # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
   location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
      access_log off; 
      log_not_found off; 
      expires max;
   }

   # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
   location ~ \.php$ {
      set $rt_session "";

      if ($http_cookie ~* "wc_session_cookie_[^=]*=([^%]+)%7C") {
                     set $rt_session wc_session_cookie_$1;
            }  

      if ($skip_cache = 0 ) {
         more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
         set $rt_session "";
      }

           fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$rt_session";

      try_files $uri =404;    


      include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/wordpress.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
           fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

      fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
      fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
   }

   location ~ /purge(/.*) {
       fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
   }  

   #location = /xmlrpc.php {
   #  deny all;
   #  access_log off;
   #  log_not_found off;
   #}

}
```

Comment: do you want you site to work with `http` or just redirect `http` to `https`?

Comment: https only.  it is a webshop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the http part to:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com 52.29.193.xxx;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root         /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and restartet nginx but it didn't worked.

Comment: You still get `403` when you try to open `http://www.example.com/`, and `https://www.example.com/` works ok?

Comment: Yes it works with https prefix but not with http or no prefix.

Comment: Is there perhaps another `.conf` file with `example.com` configuration?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the post above. But nothing was changed on this file since 2 months, instead of the first file I posted which changed yesterday.

Comment: Is there an Elastic Load Balancer in front of this instance?